# Proper use of views and subviews in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, view, angular-ui

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm struggling a little bit with my multiple views. Maybe someone can shed a light on how this should be done.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I'm trying to implement some kind of file explorer, where there are two columns: the left column contains all subfolders and files in a folder, the right column shows detail infos when a file or a folder is clicked. When the user double-clicks a folder the view should refresh and list the subfolder while the detail column should be cleared.

It's basically working more or less but the left column is refreshing always even if it shouldn't. And I'm pretty sure it's very hacky, but I don't know how to improve this.

I'm using ui-router for the multiple views and Restangular for REST-calls, which I replaced with dummy data in this example.

Bootstrapping:

```
// app.js
var app = angular.module('explorer', ['ui.compat']);
```

This is my main template:

```
// app.html
[...]
[...]
<div ui-view></div>
```

This is the container template, that is loaded at the very beginning:

```
// files.html
<div ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="details"></div>
```

This is the template for the file list on the left:

```
// files-list.html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Filename</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Modified</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="file in files">
        <td><a href="#/{{ file.type }}/{{ file.id }}">{{ file.name }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ file.size }}</td>
        <td>{{ file.modified }}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is the details template:

```
// files-details.html
<div>{{ file.name }}</div>
```

This is the first controller for displaying the list in the left column (sorry, it's CoffeScript):

```
app.controller 'ListController', ['$scope', '$state', ($scope, $state) ->
  $scope.files = [{
    "id": "12", "type": "folder", "name": "testfolder", "size": "", "modified": "01.01.2000"
  }, {
    "id": "54", "type": "file", "name": "testfile", "size": "23kb", "modified": "01.01.2000"
  }]
]
```

And this is the details controller:

```
app.controller 'DetailsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', ($scope, $stateParams) ->
  $scope.file = { "id": "54", "type": "file", "name": "testfile", "size": "23kb", "modified": "01.01.2000"};
]
```

And these are my messy routing rules:

```
app.config ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
  $urlRouterProvider
    .when('/folder', '/folder/1')

  $stateProvider.state 'list', {
    url: ''
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'files.html'
      },
      'column1@list': {
        templateUrl: 'files-list.html'
        controller: 'ListController'
      },
      'column2@list': {
        templateUrl: 'files-detail.html'
      }
    }
  }
  $stateProvider.state 'folder', {
    abstract: yes
    templateUrl: 'files-list.html'
    controller: 'ListController'
  }
  $stateProvider.state 'folder.list', {
    url: '/folder/{id}'
    templateUrl: 'files-list.html'
    controller: 'ListController'
  }

  $stateProvider.state 'list.file', {
    url: '/file/{childId}'
    views: {
      '': {
        templateUrl: 'files-list.html'
        controller: 'ListController'
      }
      'details': {
          templateUrl: 'files-detail.html'
          controller: 'DetailsController'
        }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But I see several things that you may have incorrect.

- You're using `ui.compat` module. Use `ui.state` instead. compat is for backwards compatibility if you have an existing project using `ng-view` and `routeProvider`.
- I would nest the details view *inside* the file list view. That helps because now when you switch between files, only the details view updates, not the list as well. I added a log to prove it. See my plunkr below. Navigate from the folder to the file and back several times. The "list" controller only instantiates once.
- I also merged your detail state into a single state with a url of `url: "/:type/:id"`, so it captures both /folder/id and /file/id

Here's a plunkr I made for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/6BEIs6?p=preview

---

Also you said:

> When the user double-clicks a folder the view should refresh and list
>   the subfolder while the detail column should be cleared.

So I also made a version that can root down into folders (double click them), just like a real file explorer, and you can go back up too (single click the ../).

http://plnkr.co/edit/tAjv2I?p=preview

I think its pretty good, though if I had more time it'd be nice if the url also stored your location in the folders (as opposed to just what type of file to show in the details).

---

EDIT: So I wanted to try and figure out how to make the folder path sync to the location path. Well I figured it out, but it requires doing quite a bit manually. For example I only have 1 state, with a url of "*path", which just captures the entire path even '/' characters. Then I have to parse it and make it do what I need it to. See the plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/1dDN3x?p=preview

Comment: Hey, that's pretty awesome! I already supposed I made thinks way too complicated, especially the view nesting. Thank you so much! It helped a lot and now I've learned a little bit more about AngularJS (still at the very beginning though).

Comment: It was my pleasure. I wanted something to do for a challenge anyway and this suited nicely. So thanks to you as well!